# Same comment box with bookmark URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments, facebook-social-plugins

I have a web page where I have added the facebook comments and also have added HTML bookmark to the comments section so that users can directly jump to the comments section from any other page or within the page. The problem is the moment I use the bookmark link on any other page, the comments plugin considers this as different URL and does not show the old comments on the page. Is there a way I can specify regex or any other pattern to the data-href attribute of FB comments plugin?

Example : 
My URLs are say : http://example.com/first.html and http://example.com/first.html#comments

There are comments in the first URL but when you click the second link these comments are not visible(though its the same page) as FB considers this as different page.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Facebook should not consider those two to be different in the first place (provided you specified your `og:url` correctly.) And no, you can not specify regex or patterns on the data-href attribute - you need to fill it with the correct value.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe for your quick response. I am not using og:url. Please see these 2 links (both urls points to the same page but comments are visible only on for the first url) : http://badmintonbuddy.com/badminton-courts/Pune and http://badmintonbuddy.com/badminton-courts/Pune#findpartner